# abi.decode fails to decode Structure

Tags: abi, decoding

Function reverts when trying to decode this struct:

```
    struct NftProperties {
    uint32 dateOfFirstOperation;
    uint32 timestampStart;
    uint32 timestampEnd;
    int64 equivalentCO2;
    uint64 amountOfEnergy;
    uint64 amountOfEnergyInJ;
    address organizationUnitAddress;
    bytes12 organizationId;
    bytes12 assetId;
    bytes12 signalId;
    uint32 signalQuality;
    uint32 tokenTimestamp; 
    string energyUnit;
    string assetName;
    string meterName;
    string signalName;
}
```

Here is how I call the `abi.decode:`

```
    function getReferencedToken(uint tokenID, address contractAddress) public returns (NftProperties memory){
            
            (bool success, bytes memory returnData) =
            contractAddress.staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("getTokenProperties(uint256 tokenId)", tokenID));
        
            NftProperties memory returnValue = abi.decode(returnData,(NftProperties));
        
            require(success == true, "Success is not True");
        
            return returnValue;
        }
```

And this is the called encoded function that returns struct value:

```
function getTokenProperties(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (NftProperties memory nftProperties)  {
    require(
        tokenId >= 0 && tokenIdToNftProperties[tokenId].amountOfEnergy > 0,
        "Token and it's properties for with respective tokenId must exist!"
    );
    return tokenIdToNftProperties[tokenId];
}
```

NOTE: I double-checked the proper structure is imported/declared in all contracts that have to work with it.

However, I have no idea why the function reverts at `abi.decode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Mistake:

```
"getTokenProperties(uint256 tokenId)"
```

should have been

```
"getTokenProperties(uint256)"
```